# Referring to a module with a string in Perl

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have a string with a module name and need to use this to instantiate an object. How is this best done? I am looking for something like

foo.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Bar;

my $module = "Bar";
my $obj = {$module}->new(); # does not work

$obj->fun (123);
```

Bar.pm

```
package Bar;
use strict;
sub new
{
    my $self = {};
    return bless $self;
}

sub fun
{
    my ($self, $arg);
    print "obj $self got arg $arg\n";
}
```

Comment: Have you not tried `$module->new()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're overcomplicating.  `$module->new` works just fine on its own with no {braces}:

```
$ perl -MXML::Simple -E 'use strict; my $foo = "XML::Simple"; my $obj = $foo->new; say $obj'
XML::Simple=HASH(0x9d024d8)
```

Comment: I really thought I had tried this. And I will keep wonder why it didn't work the first time. Probably I had some other error in my code. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Besides the provided notes about unnecessary braces, you could be interested in [Class::MOP](https://metacpan.org/pod/Class%3a%3aMOP) or [Class::Load](https://metacpan.org/pod/Class%3a%3aLoad) (for more recent code), especially the `load_class()` subroutine, for a *more dynamic* loading of modules/classes.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use the Perl function `eval`.
You also have to use `ref`  to get the name of a perl Object.
But first of all your foo method isn't taking the arguments, here is a corrected version :

```
package Bar;
use strict;
sub new
{
    my $self = {};
    return bless $self;
}

sub fun
{
    my ($self, $arg) = @_;
    print "obj ".ref($self)." got arg $arg\n";
}

1;
```

Here is the test script :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Bar;

my $module = "Bar";
my $obj = eval {$module->new()};

$obj->fun (123);
```

Output : 
obj Bar got arg 123

Comment: You don't need to use `eval`. `$module->new` works just fine, assuming that `$module` contains a class name, and the class provides a `new` method.

Comment: Also, avoid the one argument form of `bless`.